# How to call a new activity or external link using TreeNode/file Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck on some programming with my application that i'm creating. I'm pretty new to android.

My issue is that I want to be able to when onclick or listen on my tree node I can eithier link to an external PDF or start a new activity.
eg:

Parent

Child1

Child2

Clicking on Child2 will go to another activity class or external link.

I'm using https://github.com/mayankneeds/TreeView-Android TreeView.

My techhome.java

```
package e.phlange.login;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



import e.phlange.login.atv.model.TreeNode;
import e.phlange.login.atv.view.AndroidTreeView;

public class techhome extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_techhome);

    //Root
    TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();

    //Parent
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem nodeItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down, "Technical Library");
    TreeNode parent = new TreeNode(nodeItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), true, MyHolder.DEFAULT, MyHolder.DEFAULT));

    //Audio Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem audio_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Audio");
    TreeNode audio_child = new TreeNode(audio_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For AV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem amx_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "AMX");
    TreeNode amx_subChild = new TreeNode(amx_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For AV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem crestron_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Crestron");
    TreeNode crestron_subChild = new TreeNode(crestron_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For AV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem nexia_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Nexia");
    TreeNode nexia_subChild = new TreeNode(nexia_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For AV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem speakers_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Speakers");
    TreeNode speakers_subChild = new TreeNode(speakers_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For AV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem toa_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "TOA");
    TreeNode toa_subChild = new TreeNode(toa_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //CBUS-Lighting Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem cbus_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "CBUS & Lighting");
    TreeNode cbus_child = new TreeNode(cbus_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Lighting
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem cbus_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "CBUS");
    TreeNode cbus_subChild = new TreeNode(cbus_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Lighting
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem ecs_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "ECS Lighting");
    TreeNode ecs_subChild = new TreeNode(ecs_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //CCTV Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem cctv_childItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "CCTV");
    TreeNode cctv_child = new TreeNode(cctv_childItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For CCTV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem axis_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "AXIS");
    TreeNode axis_subChild = new TreeNode(axis_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For CCTV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem bosch_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "BOSCH");
    TreeNode bosch_subChild = new TreeNode(bosch_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For CCTV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem dahua_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "DAHUA");
    TreeNode dahua_subChild = new TreeNode(dahua_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For CCTV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem dvtel_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "DVTEL");
    TreeNode dvtel_subChild = new TreeNode(dvtel_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For CCTV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem genetec_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "GENETEC");
    TreeNode genetec_subChild = new TreeNode(genetec_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For CCTV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem indigo_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "INDIGOVISION");
    TreeNode indigo_subChild = new TreeNode(indigo_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For CCTV
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem milestone_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "MILESTONE");
    TreeNode milestone_subChild = new TreeNode(milestone_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));


    //DATA Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem data_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "DATA & Timers");
    TreeNode data_child = new TreeNode(data_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For DATA
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem adam_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "ADAM");
    TreeNode adam_subChild = new TreeNode(adam_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For DATA
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem lantronixs_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "LANTRONIXS");
    TreeNode lantronixs_subChild = new TreeNode(lantronixs_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For DATA
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem protection_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Protection Devices");
    TreeNode protection_subChild = new TreeNode(protection_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For DATA
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem timers_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Timers & MISC");
    TreeNode timers_subChild = new TreeNode(timers_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //FIRE Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem fire_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "FIRE");
    TreeNode fire_child = new TreeNode(fire_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Fire
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem ampac_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "AMPAC");
    TreeNode ampac_subChild = new TreeNode(ampac_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Fire
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem inertia_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "INERTIA");
    TreeNode inertia_subChild = new TreeNode(inertia_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Fire
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem notifier_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "NOTIFIER");
    TreeNode notifier_subChild = new TreeNode(notifier_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Fire
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem simplex_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "SIMPLEX");
    TreeNode simplex_subChild = new TreeNode(simplex_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Fire
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem vesda_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "VESDA");
    TreeNode vesda_subChild = new TreeNode(vesda_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Fire
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem vigilant_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "VIGILANT");
    TreeNode vigilant_subChild = new TreeNode(vigilant_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Gates and Sensors Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem gates_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Gates & Sensors");
    TreeNode gates_child = new TreeNode(gates_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Gates
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem gates_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Coming Soon");
    TreeNode gates_subChild = new TreeNode(gates_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Locks Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem locks_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Locks");
    TreeNode locks_child = new TreeNode(locks_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Locks
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem mortise_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Coming Soon");
    TreeNode mortise_subChild = new TreeNode(mortise_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Intercoms Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem intercom_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Intercoms");
    TreeNode intercom_child = new TreeNode(intercom_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Intercom
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem aiphone_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "AIPHONE");
    TreeNode aiphone_subChild = new TreeNode(aiphone_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Intercom
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem bticino_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "BTICINO");
    TreeNode bticino_subChild = new TreeNode(bticino_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Intercom
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem dallasdelta_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "DALLAS DELTA");
    TreeNode dallasdelta_subChild = new TreeNode(dallasdelta_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Intercom
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem cellcall_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "CELL CALL");
    TreeNode cellcall_subChild = new TreeNode(cellcall_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Intercom
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem elvox_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "ELVOX");
    TreeNode elvox_subChild = new TreeNode(elvox_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Intercom
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem jacques_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "JACQUES");
    TreeNode jacques_subChild = new TreeNode(jacques_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Intercom
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem kocom_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "KOCOM");
    TreeNode kocom_subChild = new TreeNode(kocom_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));


    //Nursecall Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem nursecall_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Nursecall");
    TreeNode nursecall_child = new TreeNode(nursecall_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Nursecall
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem austco_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Austco");
    TreeNode austco_subChild = new TreeNode(austco_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Nursecall
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem questek_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Questek");
    TreeNode questek_subChild = new TreeNode(questek_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));


    //Sub Child For Nursecall
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem sedco_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Sedco");
    TreeNode sedco_subChild = new TreeNode(sedco_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));


    //Paging & DECT Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem paging_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Paging & DECT");
    TreeNode paging_child = new TreeNode(paging_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem ascom_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "ASCOM");
    TreeNode ascom_subChild = new TreeNode(ascom_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem basepage_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Basepage");
    TreeNode basepage_subChild = new TreeNode(basepage_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem bravo_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "BRAVO PAGERS");
    TreeNode bravo_subChild = new TreeNode(bravo_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem fusion_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "FUSION");
    TreeNode fusion_subChild = new TreeNode(fusion_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem genie_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "GENIE PAGERS");
    TreeNode genie_subChild = new TreeNode(genie_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem kirk_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "KIRK");
    TreeNode kirk_subChild = new TreeNode(kirk_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem messenger_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "MESSENGER");
    TreeNode messenger_subChild = new TreeNode(messenger_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Paging
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem nec_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "NEC PAGERS");
    TreeNode nec_subChild = new TreeNode(nec_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Security Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem security_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Security");
    TreeNode security_child = new TreeNode(security_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem ademco_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "ADEMCO");
    TreeNode ademco_subChild = new TreeNode(ademco_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem andover_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "ANDOVER");
    TreeNode andover_subChild = new TreeNode(andover_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem biometrics_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "BIOMETRICS");
    TreeNode biometrics_subChild = new TreeNode(biometrics_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem boschsec_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "BOSCH");
    TreeNode boschsec_subChild = new TreeNode(boschsec_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem bqt_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "BQT");
    TreeNode bqt_subChild = new TreeNode(bqt_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem cardax_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "CARDAX");
    TreeNode cardax_subChild = new TreeNode(cardax_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem concept_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "CONCEPT");
    TreeNode concept_subChild = new TreeNode(concept_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem das_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "DAS/RELIANCE");
    TreeNode das_subChild = new TreeNode(das_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem honeywell_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "HONEYWELL");
    TreeNode honeywell_subChild = new TreeNode(honeywell_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem keywatcher_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Keywatcher");
    TreeNode keywatcher_subChild = new TreeNode(keywatcher_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem ness_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "NESS");
    TreeNode ness_subChild = new TreeNode(ness_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem nidac_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "NIDAC");
    TreeNode nidac_subChild = new TreeNode(nidac_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem paradox_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "PARADOX");
    TreeNode paradox_subChild = new TreeNode(paradox_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem risco_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "RISCO");
    TreeNode risco_subChild = new TreeNode(risco_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem rosslare_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "ROSSLARE");
    TreeNode rosslare_subChild = new TreeNode(rosslare_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem securitel_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Securitel & GSM");
    TreeNode securitel_subChild = new TreeNode(securitel_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem secescort_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Security Escort");
    TreeNode secescort_subChild = new TreeNode(secescort_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem sentrol_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Sentrol");
    TreeNode sentrol_subChild = new TreeNode(sentrol_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem siemans_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Siemans");
    TreeNode siemans_subChild = new TreeNode(siemans_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem solution_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Solution");
    TreeNode solution_subChild = new TreeNode(solution_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem tecom_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "TECOM");
    TreeNode tecom_subChild = new TreeNode(tecom_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));

    //Sub Child For Security
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem tecom1_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "TECOM1");
    final TreeNode tecom1_subChild = new TreeNode(tecom1_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 250));

    //Wireless Child
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem wireless_ChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "Wireless");
    TreeNode wireless_child = new TreeNode(wireless_ChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 25));

    //Sub Child For Wireless
    MyHolder.IconTreeItem inovonics_subChildItem = new MyHolder.IconTreeItem(R.drawable.ic_folder, "INOVONICS");
    TreeNode inovonics_subChild = new TreeNode(inovonics_subChildItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getApplicationContext(), false, R.layout.child, 150));


    //Audio Child
    audio_child.addChild(amx_subChild);
    audio_child.addChild(crestron_subChild);
    audio_child.addChild(nexia_subChild);
    audio_child.addChild(speakers_subChild);
    audio_child.addChild(toa_subChild);

    //Lighting Child
    cbus_child.addChild(cbus_subChild);
    cbus_child.addChild(ecs_subChild);

    //CCTV Child
    cctv_child.addChild(axis_subChild);
    cctv_child.addChild(bosch_subChild);
    cctv_child.addChild(dahua_subChild);
    cctv_child.addChild(dvtel_subChild);
    cctv_child.addChild(genetec_subChild);
    cctv_child.addChild(indigo_subChild);
    cctv_child.addChild(milestone_subChild);

    //DATA Child
    data_child.addChild(adam_subChild);
    data_child.addChild(lantronixs_subChild);
    data_child.addChild(protection_subChild);
    data_child.addChild(timers_subChild);

    //FIRE Child
    fire_child.addChild(ampac_subChild);
    fire_child.addChild(inertia_subChild);
    fire_child.addChild(notifier_subChild);
    fire_child.addChild(simplex_subChild);
    fire_child.addChild(vesda_subChild);
    fire_child.addChild(vigilant_subChild);

    //Gates Child
    gates_child.addChild(gates_subChild);

    //Locks Child
    locks_child.addChild(mortise_subChild);

    //Intercoms Child
    intercom_child.addChild(aiphone_subChild);
    intercom_child.addChild(bticino_subChild);
    intercom_child.addChild(cellcall_subChild);
    intercom_child.addChild(dallasdelta_subChild);
    intercom_child.addChild(elvox_subChild);
    intercom_child.addChild(jacques_subChild);
    intercom_child.addChild(kocom_subChild);


    //Nursecall
    nursecall_child.addChild(austco_subChild);
    nursecall_child.addChild(questek_subChild);
    nursecall_child.addChild(sedco_subChild);

    //PAGING Child
    paging_child.addChild(ascom_subChild);
    paging_child.addChild(basepage_subChild);
    paging_child.addChild(bravo_subChild);
    paging_child.addChild(fusion_subChild);
    paging_child.addChild(genie_subChild);
    paging_child.addChild(kirk_subChild);
    paging_child.addChild(messenger_subChild);
    paging_child.addChild(nec_subChild);

    //Security Child
    security_child.addChild(ademco_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(andover_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(biometrics_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(boschsec_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(bqt_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(cardax_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(concept_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(das_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(honeywell_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(keywatcher_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(ness_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(nidac_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(paradox_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(risco_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(rosslare_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(securitel_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(secescort_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(sentrol_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(siemans_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(solution_subChild);
    security_child.addChild(tecom_subChild);

    tecom_subChild.addChild(tecom1_subChild);

    //Wireless Child
    wireless_child.addChild(inovonics_subChild);


    //Main Parents
    parent.addChildren(audio_child);
    parent.addChildren(cctv_child);
    parent.addChildren(cbus_child);
    parent.addChildren(data_child);
    parent.addChildren(fire_child);
    parent.addChildren(gates_child);
    parent.addChildren(intercom_child);
    parent.addChildren(locks_child);
    parent.addChildren(nursecall_child);
    parent.addChildren(paging_child);
    parent.addChildren(security_child);
    parent.addChildren(wireless_child);


    root.addChild(parent);

    //Add AndroidTreeView into view.
    AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getApplicationContext(), root);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_parent)).addView(tView.getView());

}
}
```

My activity for techhome (activity_techome.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ll_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context="e.phlange.login.techhome">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. The code I needed to achieve this was:

```
tecom1_subChild.setClickListener(new TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Testing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```